# How this query is returning me 1100 value if there is no salary against the foreign key 30

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Write a query to get the minimum salary of department number 30,
the salary should add commission

```
select *
from emp

select *
from dept

select min(sal+comm) as 'sal+com'
from emp
where deptno = 3

select min(sal+comm) as 'sal+comm'
from emp, dept
where dept.deptno = 30
```

This is the question and the queries I tried they both are giving me different outputs but how its giving 1100 if there is no foreign key of 30 in emp table.

[image: 1]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: First off Sal+Comm where Comm is null will equal NULL

Comment: Secondly your second query is basically a CROSS JOIN.   Use the explicit JOIN ... ON ...

Comment: You demonstrate why NO ONE should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: @NikhilVartak Nope.  All the values would be null except for ones with a COMM value... which is 1100.   He as created a one to many.  Each dept has EVERY emp record.

Comment: @SMor OP seems new to MSSQL. I think that link, although good one, will confuse him.

Comment: #1. Use isnull(comm, 0) #2. Do proper inner join ON deptno. There's no other rocket here.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I realized that, so removed the comment. You were fast enough to read it.

Comment: @NikhilVartak "OP seems new to MSSQL. I think that link, although good one, will confuse him." - I don't think you can explain it any simpler than that. The onus is on the OP to up-school themselves if they don't understand the assistance provided. (Also its recommended to use gender neutral language e.g. they rather than him).

Answer (score 1):

Your query has basically said for every row in emp select every row in dept and filter the results where dept has a dept no of 30. Even though you have a foreign key you still have to specify the join in the select.  The FL is more about referential integrity.

Try

```
 select min(sal+comm) as "sal+comm"
 from emp inner join dept
 on dept.deptno=emp.deptno
 where dept.deptno=30
```

However because you have null in the commission column sal+comm might equal null. So use `min(isnull(sal,0) + isnull(comm,0))`

And finally you don't actually need the dept table as you are querying on a value that is already in the emp table so

```
select min(isnull(sal,0)+isnull(comm,0)) as "sal+comm"
from emp
where deptno=30
```

Comment: "you don't actually need the dept table" - hi @BobVale what if they have not set cascading rules on dept table and one of the dept is removed!?

Comment: @NikhilVartak Sorry - You don't need the dept table in this particular select, not you don't need the dept table full stop.  If there is no cascade rule set on the FK relationship then the SQL server will prevent you deleting a dept.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you're select from two tables, but you haven't specified a criterion to join the two tables. This result in a cross join, that means you have a cartesian product of First table tuples with second tables tuples.
You can try adding a clause where you say "and emp.deptno = dept.deptno"